# How do i split the CJSON parsing or cJSON_Print

Tags: c, json, cjson

I have checked the documentation:
https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON#parsing-json and https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON#printing-json.

My question is I have a function `void foo (char *JSON);` that can only accept size_t JSON string representation at a time. The JSON String is larger than size_t.
Either I can parse the full JSON and print it in size_t chunks or I would have to split the JSON string into size_t and sanitize it to retain it in well-formed JSON format.

Is there a CJSON API that could help me in any of the scenarios?

Comment: *The JSON String is larger than size_t.*?  What OS/hardware are you running on?  You're not getting 4+ GB of JSON on a 32-bit system, are you?!?!  That'd be one horrid, unthinking design decision:  "Let's feed multiple GB of JSON to 32-bit processors!!!"  The stupid is strong there.  There might be a streaming JSON parser that fits your needs, but product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: There are definitely better options then cjson if working with such huge json texts.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the question.
The size_t is not very large. The external embedded device code ```function foo``` has some basic size restrictions. We are already using CJSON for the c code. Please recommend some solution.

Comment: What is the size of your size_t?